# Remove Duplicate Items From Multidimensional Array Using Javascript, jQuery, & underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I have a web page which uses jQuery to fetch data from a JSON file that contains a location name, latitude, and longitude.  I then push the retrieved data into an array.

```
 var weatherSites = [];
 function weather() {
    $.getJSON('json/LOCS.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data.locations, function() {
       var locationLatitude = this.latitude;
       var locationLongitude = this.longitude;
       var locationName = this.location;
       // -- If the latitude and longitude are 0,0 then skip to the next iteration --
            if (locationtLatitude == +0 || locationLatitude == -0 && locationLongitude == +0 || locationLongitude == -0) {
                return true;
            }

       // Populate array with site name, latitude, and longitude       
       weatherSites.push({name: locationName, latitude: locationLatitude, longitude: locationLongitude});

    });
  });

  };
```

The code retrieves the data and populates the array as required.  However, there are a number of `locationName` items which are the same, even though the `locationLatitude` and/or `locationLongitude` are different.  I need to remove from the array elements where the `locationName`s are the same, regardless of the latitude or longitude.

I have tried using a number of methods seen here but have had no luck.  For example:

```
function removeDupes() {
        var uniques = _.map(_.groupBy(weatherSites,function(doc){
          return doc.id;
        }),function(grouped){
          return grouped[0];
        });
```

This example requires underscore.js.  This did not work for me.  I am new to programming and GIS in general.  I would appreciate an answer which contains the full code necessary and hopefully the logic behind what is happening.  This would be very helpful for me and will of course help me to learn.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: this would be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open source project http://www.jinqJs.com can easily do it.
Here is the GitHub link: [GitHub](https://github.com/fordth/jinqJs)

```
var results = jinqJs()
                  .from(data1)
                  .groupBy('locationName')
                  .max('locationLatitude', 'locationLongitude')
                  .select();
```

Let me know if you need any working examples.